# 年月のみの日時データを作成する方法について

Tags: r

```
> as.Date("2017/12/25")
[1] "2017-12-25"
> as.Date("2017/12")
charToDate(x) でエラー: 
   文字列は標準的な曖昧さのない書式にはなっていません 
>
```

上記、年と月のみの日時データを作成したいのですが
方法を教えてくださいお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Date (日付）は日本語が示すように日を単位とする型ですから、月を単位とする型（年月のみ）を表現するのに適していません。

どの月も最初の日は"１日"ですから、月の初日で年月を代表させるといった工夫(方便)が必要です。

例えばseq関数を使って、

```
yyyymm <- seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), as.Date("2018/12/31"), "months")
```

"2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-05-01" "2018-06-01" ・・・ "2018-11-01" "2018-12-01"というベクトルを作り、
これらを 2018/01, 2018/02 ... 2018/12 の年月のデータ（日時データ）として扱うというふうに。

===
もちろん、年月のクラス(ここでは YearMonthクラスとします）を自分で定義しても良いと思います。Dateクラスを参考にすれば、そんなに難しくないと思います。

> > as.YearMonth("2017/12")
> >     [1] "2017-12"